# React - How to check equality for state variable declared with useState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following example I declare a variable `myVar` with useState() hook. I am trying to check its value and according to this do some things. I know through the useEffect() hook that `myVar` has the value it is supposed to have. Though when I try to check if it's equal with some value in if statements, those comparisons are clearly calculated wrong. Is there some workaround to ckeck `myVar` variable's value? Thank you in advance!

```
const Example = () => {

    const [myVar, setMyVar] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        // Consoles the correct value
        console.log(myVar);
    }, [myVar])

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            if (!loading) {
                await runAnimation();
            }
        })()
    }, [loading])

    const runAnimation = async () => {
        setMyVar(myVar + 1);
        someFunction();
    }

    const someFunction = async () => {
        response = await controls.start();
        // Gets in wrong statements
        if (myVar === 0) {
            doZero();
        } else if (myVar === 1) {
            doOne();
        } else if (myVar === 2) {
            setMyVar(myVar - 1);
            doTwo();
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <SomeComponents />
        </div>
    )

}
```

Comment: please explain why "those comparisons are clearly calculated wrong". That's really not apparent from your code. The function where the comparison is happening isn't even called.

Comment: They are clearly calculated wrong, because through useEffect I see that myVar has value 1, but the doZero function gets called instead of the doOne. The app consists of many files and dependencies, I cannot upload the whole app.

Comment: Can you add the code where you call `someFunction`? The bug is probably caused by a stale closure variable, but there's no way to be more specific without seeing the code.

Comment: Calling `setMyVar` is not going to change any local variables, so `someFunction` on the next line is still going to be working with the same values you had before you called it. Depending on what you're trying to do you could either modify `someFunction` to take in a parameter and you pass in the new value, or you could set it up to run the next time the component renders via a `useEffect`